# Container Size not being reported correctly from RCTUIManager.measure and onLayout

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Good afternoon,

I am trying to programmatically scroll a ScrollView that holds a view container that is larger than the ScrollView in true size. However the ScrollView needs to cut off the container at a predetermined size. So if the ScrollView height is 600px and the container size is 1000px then I need access to the 1000px so I can scroll fluidly programmatically. This issue was solved on github for another developer here but this doesn't seem to be working for me. Here is what I have tried:

`<ScrollView>
     <View onLayout={(event) => {console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout);}>
     ...
     </View>
</ScrollView>`

Attempt 1: Put an onLayout callback in both the scrollView and the inner View and use the innerViews layout height. 
Result: This didn't work both the ScrollView and inner View are reporting a height of 600.

Attempt 2: Save reference to the ScrollView and then call RCTUIManager's measure function at a later point like so:

`RCTUIManager.measure(this.refs.scrollView.getInnerViewNode(), (...data)=>{console.log(data)});`

Result: This didn't work either, the innerViewNode is reporting a container height (4th parameter in data) of 600 again.

Anyone have a difference solution to receiving the container height? I am definitely putting a 1000ish px view within a 600ish px scroll view and when I scroll programmatically say 100px, I can see that the content is actually bigger than the ScrollView wrapper.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I found to work:

```
<ScrollView>
     {{...components of variable length...}}
     <View key="bottomMarker" onLayout={() => {console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.y)}}></View>
</ScrollView>
```

By using the View as a marker for the bottom, you can find the location of the bottom of the scroll view.